# I can't figure out how to apply a once only cookie to my JavaScript "on-page load" popup

Tags: javascript, cookies, popup

For some reason I can't figure out where to put the argument to not show the pop up if it already appeared once for the individual.

```js
$(function(){
var overlay = $('<div id="overlay"></div>');
overlay.show();
overlay.appendTo(document.body);
$('.popup').show();
$('.close').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});


 

$('.x').click(function(){
$('.popup').hide();
overlay.appendTo(document.body).remove();
return false;
});
});
```

I've tried, but for some reason I keep getting it wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Where do you set your cookies? I don't see any code related to that.

Comment: That's my issue. I'm not even sure where to start. I'm very new to this.